# Not getting notification call of document update from google drive api while G Suite Integration

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-docs-api, google-workspace

I am trying to integrate google drive api with my web application , I am facing issue in getting notification for update document . I am getting notification for trash & sync but in case of update document I am not getting any notifications.

I have configured all things as written in https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/push  , Please help me if anybody have idea about my issue.

Please find below end point which I have implemented to get notification when I edit/update doc file in Google drive .

```
 @RequestMapping("/notifications")
 public ResponseEntity<String> postNotification(HttpServletRequest request)
 {
  log.info("==========in notification start===============");
  for (Enumeration<?> e = request.getHeaderNames(); e.hasMoreElements();)
  {
   String nextHeaderName = (String) e.nextElement();
   String headerValue = request.getHeader(nextHeaderName);

   log.info("nextHeaderName=" + nextHeaderName);
   log.info("headerValue=" + headerValue);
   log.info("================");
  }
  log.info("==========in notification end===============");
  return ResponseEntity.status(200).build();
 }
```

Comment: What does your code look like that doesn't work? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @Mr.Rebot I have edited & put code of my end point , I am not getting notification call after I open doc file and start editing it.